# I am trying to get profile information from facebook and not able to get the Email id using the access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate facebook login and get profile information from facebook after succesfull login , only name and id is sent back but not the Email id and other information using the access token . It was working fine before the new developer.facebook update was released.

below is the code for getting the profile information which was working fine 3 weeks before

```
FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "{app key}";
        FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "{app secret key}";

    string code="AQBTVfDZeWbLf3qzYJbexweZJNc-mBl5tPYBx5rIE6GN_0YciFoDajKd3U6jRdtG1vzdxdiieUY2ZFLapY7MLYIXgkHu3ye-ZGVlUZdsbu9GZHlw1rZ9yK8IKJlX20mIp3Qi5TqkA1ODdOEJcst2KlmRTwPUxk7chgfDew8A1R4Bs3A3HFQp23LyCOhgWfQlDwjNaizseBa6FffY7lQlvWpkEncah2_oiY5eZIdv4Iw172ulRcAf4OM824JlM5CmjJUWUyz1hVEAs9OIEvGPKjyW51LMOkoU7fjnOpF7bQtPuHfYRuQjvtsbPnCNx0pC89ndAZvhIKEGWBenN3WFXDdAGS"



     string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
                    FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
                    faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);
                    pnlFaceBookUser.Visible = true;
                    lblId.Text = faceBookUser.Id;
                    lblUserName.Text = faceBookUser.UserName;
                    lblName.Text = faceBookUser.Name;
                    lblEmail.Text = faceBookUser.Email;
                    ProfileImage.ImageUrl = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
                    lblBirthday.Text = faceBookUser.Birthday; 


public class FaceBookUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public FaceBookEntity Location { get; set; }
}

public class FaceBookEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

suggest me with solution to get the email id of the login using access token

Comment: Most probably the email field is empty, which means that it was not provided by a user. You will not be able to get any data except Name, Last name and Email without facebook's approval that you really need this data in your app.

Comment: Second reason might be your Diserialize class, which is facing some difficulties, while parsing JSON.

Comment: same Facebook account I use to sign in and I use to get id, username, EmailID. since 3 weeks I am facing this issue.